# GitLab API: how to create a merge request note with a position?

Tags: api, gitlab

I can successfully create "general" merge request notes using following API:

```
POST /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/notes
```

However, when trying to add a `position` object to the `POST` request, it will be ignored. For my experiments, I've tried to use exactly the same position object as it's reported when querying merge request information:

```
type:   "DiffNote"
body:   "+6x1"
position:   
  base_sha:     "b1f8788c186e0120ccae93797cd280fa28a0ef3c"
  start_sha:    "b1f8788c186e0120ccae93797cd280fa28a0ef3c"
  head_sha:         "27ce170fcd248f980679f8ffd104c9b600141db1"
  old_path:         "file1.txt"
  new_path:         "file1.txt"
  position_type:    "text"
  old_line:         null
  new_line:         5
```